# Unresolved EJS variable on PhpStorm IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, ejs

PhpStorm keeps saying a variable within an EJS file is unresolved, even though my code compiles and runs with no issues. I have plugins for both EJS and node installed so not sure how to remove this message please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [WEB-14427](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14427) for updates; as a workaround, you can create a dummy `.js` file (not a module, i.e. it shouldn't export or require anything) and define your variable there using JSdoc, like

```
/**
 * @name kindOfDay
 */
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Shame to see it's an issue which has been around for some time now but appreciate to know it's logged somewhere. I may leave this question open in case someone may can back to it once the issue is fixed but have upvoted your answer. Thanks again.